# Attempt to open PDF with PDFPlumber results in FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, pdf, text

I have python script that is called by VBA that loops through whatever folder the excel workbook is in and then returns the PDF in that folder (as there will only ever be one) and then is suppose to open it and return the text; However I get following Errors and I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Path...", line 16, in <module>
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file) as pdf:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfplumber\pdf.py", line 54, in open
    fp = open(path_or_fp, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Company - Terms - Jan 01.pdf'
```

Code:

```
"""Declare Variables"""
FILE_PATH = 'C:/Users/Path...'
dir_list = os.listdir(FILE_PATH)
pdf_file = ''

'Find the PDF in the folder'
for file in dir_list:
    file_type = file[file.find('.'):len(file)]
    if file_type == '.pdf':
        pdf_file = file
        with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file) as pdf:
            page = pdf.pages[0]
            text = page.extract_text()
        continue

print(text)
```

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns a list of file names, not paths, so it looks like you need to set `pdf_file = os.path.join(FILE_PATH, file)` to make what you pass `pdfplumber.open()` the full path to the file.

Comment: Note that `os.path.splitext(file) == '.pdf'` would be easier.  Alternatively, use `for file in glob.glob(FILE_PATH+'/*.pdf')`.  That returns on the files you want, AND includes the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not passing the full path of the pdf file to `pdfplumber.open()`. I would suggest that you use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module whenever to you have to deal with the manipulation of paths to files and directory folders. Doing so would make your code look like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

FOLDER_PATH = Path('C:/Users/Path...')

# Find the PDFs in the folder
for pdf_file in FOLDER_PATH.glob('*.pdf'):
    with pdfplumber.open(str(pdf_file)) as pdf:
        page = pdf.pages[0]
        text = page.extract_text()
        print(text)
```

Note you may not need the `str(pdf_file)` depending on whether `pdfplumber.open()` accepts a `Path` object as an argument (as modern Python software should) or not.